# construction some extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f(X)$ $\in$ $F[X]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $m$, and let $(f)$ be the ideal generated by $f$. Consider the quotient ring $F[X]/(f(X))$, and write $x$ for the image of $X$ in $F[X]/(f(X))$.

The map $$P(X)\mapsto P(x):F[X]\to F[x]$$ is a homomorphism sending $f(X)$ to $0$, therefore, $f(x)=0$

I have confused the notation.

First, $P(X)$ and $P(x)$ I guess that means the same coefficient, but in a different variable, am I right?

Next, in the function $P(x):F[X]\to F[x]$, how can this be possible? I mean "$x$" is an image of $X$, but in the domain of $P(x)$, we only get the function $g(X)\in F[X]$, I have no idea to understand this function, and how to get the answer that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: $x$ is not a variable. It is the residue class of $X$ modulo the ideal $(f)$. You can denote it by $\overline X$ if you like. That's why $\overline{f(X)}=\overline 0$ or $f(x)=0$.

Comment: well, then how to understand this $P(x): F[X]\to F[x]$, this is not a function ?

Comment: That is nothing but the canonical surjection $F[X]\to F[X]/(f)$.

Comment: well, hahaha. I think that I misinterpret the thing, I realize the text  express that it is the function $F[X]\to F[x]$ where in practice, $P(X) \mapsto P(x)$

Comment: It would have been better if some other letter, say $\alpha$, had been used instead of $x$, and maybe $g$ instead of $f$ for the polynomial. “Write $\alpha$ for the image of $X$ in $F[X]/(g)$.” Was the author of your text so typographically impoverished that they couldn’t get away from effs and exes?